# How to draw ICON in GDI+?

Tags: gdi+, gdi, winapi

I want load ICON from exe's resource and draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538) and look for ReadIconFromEXEFile