# Draw Resource Icon on Button

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I would like to draw my program's icon on an "owner-drawn" button.  This could be either an icon in the resource file, or the generic Windows icon.  But, even after endless searching, I have not been able to find the code for this.  I have come across bits and pieces of answers.  But, no complete explanations.

Sorry that I have no code to post.  I am totally lost on this one.  Either standard Win API or GDI+ will work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw ICON in GDI+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286152/how-to-draw-icon-in-gdi)

Comment: Please post some code so we understand the framework you are working in.

Comment: No, unfortunately, that link just led me down a rabbit hole, and I never found the bottom.  I followed link after link, with no answers.  There must be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the button, add [`BS_ICON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/controls/button-styles?redirectedfrom=MSDN) style, then get the handle to your icon, you can use [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew).

Finally send [`BM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/controls/bm-setimage?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message with the handle to your icon.

Here is the code sample:

```
HWND button1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("OK"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_ICON,
    50, 50, 50, 50, hwnd, (HMENU)1001, hInstance, NULL);
HICON hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage( // returns a HANDLE so we have to cast to HICON
    NULL,             // hInstance must be NULL when loading from a file
    L"iconname.ico",   // the icon file name
    IMAGE_ICON,       // specifies that the file is an icon
    0,                // width of the image (we'll specify default later on)
    0,                // height of the image
    LR_LOADFROMFILE |  // we want to load a file (as opposed to a resource)
    LR_DEFAULTSIZE |   // default metrics based on the type (IMAGE_ICON, 32x32)
    LR_SHARED         // let the system release the handle when it's no longer used
);
SendMessage(button1, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hIcon);
```

Comment: Thanks Zhu Song.  We had an ice storm here.  So, the clean-up hasn't given me much chance to code.  I will try to get to it, in a couple days.